# Referencing CDI managed bean from Facelets error page

Tags: jsf-2, error-handling, weblogic, cdi, facelets

I'm having a hard time trying to get a generic error-page to work in a (really simple) WAR project that uses JSF 2, Facelets and CDI.

My application server is WebLogic 12c, which should support all of this out-of-the-box, but it fails to show the error page. When I deploy the exact same WAR to a Glassfish application server, it works.

I'm leaning towards blaming WebLogic for being buggy in the CDI department, but could use some additional expertise to see if my approach is wrong.

Here's what my application is trying to proof:

***One can reference an already existing CDI managed bean from an error page after a redirect to it has been performed***

The project holds a single `@SessionScoped` managed bean that is used to generates content that is shown on both the *welcome* page as well as the *error* page.

The welcome page displays content generated by the `@SessionScoped` bean, and uses a `@RequestScoped` bean to just throw a `(Runtime)?Exception` (which in turn initiates a redirect to the error page).

Here's my relevant code:

---

- **web/WEB-INF/beans.xml**

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
  </beans>
  ```
- **web/WEB-INF/web.xml**

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
      <context-param>
          <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
          <param-value>Development</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <servlet>
          <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
      <session-config>
          <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
      </session-config>
      <welcome-file-list>
          <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
      <error-page>
          <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
          <location>/faces/error.xhtml?faces-redirect=true</location>
      </error-page>
      <error-page>
          <error-code>500</error-code>
          <location>/faces/error.xhtml?faces-redirect=true</location>
      </error-page>
  </web-app>
  ```
- **web/error.xhtml**

  ```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
      <h:head>
          <title>Error page</title>
      </h:head>
      <h:body>
          <h1>You are now on the error page</h1>

          <h3>Current milliseconds: #{sessionScopedBean.milliseconds}</h3>
      </h:body>
  </html>
  ```
- **web/index.xhtml**

  ```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
      <h:head>
          <title>Generate exception</title>
      </h:head>
      <h:body>
          <h1>Please generate an exception of some sorts</h1>

          <h1>Current milliseconds: #{sessionScopedBean.milliseconds}</h1>

          <h:form>
              <h:commandButton action="#{exceptionGeneratingBean.generateException()}" value="Exception" />
              <h:commandButton action="#{exceptionGeneratingBean.generateRuntimeException()}" value="RuntimeException" />
          </h:form>
      </h:body>
  </html>
  ```
- **src/java/nl/rensvanleeuwen/bean/ExceptionGeneratingBean.java**

  ```
  package nl.rensvanleeuwen.bean;

  import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
  import javax.inject.Named;

  @RequestScoped
  @Named
  public class ExceptionGeneratingBean {

      public void generateRuntimeExcetion() {
          throw new RuntimeException("Here is the exception!");
      }

      public void generateException() throws Exception {
          throw new Exception("Here is the exception!");
      }
  }
  ```
- **src/java/nl/rensvanleeuwen/bean/SessionScopedBean.java**

  ```
  package nl.rensvanleeuwen.bean;

  import java.io.Serializable;
  import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
  import javax.inject.Named;

  @Named
  @SessionScoped
  public class SessionScopedBean implements Serializable {

      public long getMilliseconds() {
          return System.currentTimeMillis();
      }
  }
  ```

When I deploy this to Glassfish 3.1.2, I get the following output when one of the buttons is pressed:

---

### You are now on the error page

#### Current milliseconds: 1377897262568

---

On WebLogic, on the other hand it blows up, and the following stacktrace is shown:

```
####<Aug 30, 2013 11:24:26 PM CEST> <Error> <HTTP> <rens7> <131Server> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1377897866330> <BEA-101107> <[ServletContext@2045981067[app:_appsdir_ErrorPageTest_war module:ErrorPageTest.war path:null spec-version:3.0]] Problem occurred while serving the error page.
javax.servlet.ServletException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
  at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:338)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:221)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:564)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:263)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ForwardAction.run(ForwardAction.java:22)
  at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
  at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
  at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ErrorManager.handleException(ErrorManager.java:144)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.handleThrowableFromInvocation(WebAppServletContext.java:2239)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2089)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1514)
  at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused By: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
  at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:612)
  at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:71)
  at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
  at nl.rensvanleeuwen.bean.SessionScopedBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getMilliseconds(SessionScopedBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
  at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:305)
  at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
  at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
  at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:138)
  at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:184)
  at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
  at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
  at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:227)
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:150)
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
  at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
  at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
  at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
  at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
  at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:338)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:221)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:564)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:263)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ForwardAction.run(ForwardAction.java:22)
  at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
  at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
  at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ErrorManager.handleException(ErrorManager.java:144)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.handleThrowableFromInvocation(WebAppServletContext.java:2239)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2089)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1514)
  at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
>
```

I haven't been able to make this construct work. Does anybody have any pointers to stuff that I might have overlooked?

Comment: Your code is accurate, it looks to be a weblogic specific issue.

Comment: @JohnAment I've reported the issue at Oracle and they now have logged a bug against WebLogic Server. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ball is in the court of Oracle now. Bug 17410908 was reported against WebLogic 12.1.1.0.

Comment: It's was solved? I have this problem and I can't solve

Comment: Hi Fabio, I don't know. I don't work on the project that was suffering from this problem anymore. A quick Google shows that the issues that I mentioned before (`17410908`) is listed in an overview of patches for WebLogic. Can't verify that that implies that it was properly fixed though.