# java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebXml is not initialized yet. Please use #init(ServletContext) method to manually initialize it

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, omnifaces, weblogic12c

I'm trying to (auto) deploy an ear that holds code that uses a combination of JSF, PrimeFaces and OmniFaces on a WebLogic 12c application server.

Every now and then (and lately there's more 'now' than 'then') all of the AJAX requests that can be are done from the application are broken. Whenever something is using AJAX, the following response is returned from the server:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebXml is not initialized yet. Please use #init&#40;ServletContext&#41; method to manually initialize it.
  at org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.checkInitialized(WebXml.java:313)
  at org.omnifaces.config.WebXml.getFormLoginPage(WebXml.java:294)
  at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext$OmniPartialResponseWriter.startDocument(OmniPartialViewContext.java:253)
  at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:133)
  at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:199)
  at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:123)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
  at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:338)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
  at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
  at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:74)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3296)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3262)
  at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
  at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
  at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2171)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2097)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2075)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1514)
  at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

In that whole stacktrace, there's not a single line of code that has been written by us.

For sake of clarity, this is what we package (irrelevant items excluded; at least, let's hope they are irrelevent :):

```
portal.ear
portal.ear/portal.war
portal.ear/portal.war/WEB-INF/lib/portal.jar
portal.ear/portal.war/WEB-INF/lib/omnifaces-1.6.3.jar
portal.ear/portal.war/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.5.17.jar
```

The `web.xml` only has a single error page because of the issues mentioned at [Referencing CDI managed bean from Facelets error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542209/referencing-cdi-managed-bean-from-facelets-error-page):

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
  <location>/login.xhtml?custom_msg=session_expired</location>
</error-page>
```

Question now is: what am I doing wrong? Or is this caused by OmniFaces in combination with the before mentioned software stack?

Regards,

Rens

Comment: As first step, have you checked the server startup logs? Sure that there isn't a SEVERE log entry with message *"WebXml failed to initialize. Perhaps your web.xml contains a typo?"* and a stacktrace?

Comment: I glanced into the server logs, but did not scan it line by line. I haven't done so because the very same EAR returns different outcomes. Sometimes a restart helps, or cleaning the staging directories.

Comment: Hm right. It'll probably be caused by a race condition of `FacesContext` not being available during Weblogic's init for some reason. For now, your best bet is to create a `@WebListener` class implementing `ServletContextListener` which does `WebXml.INSTANCE.init(event.getServletContext())` in `contextInitilaized()`. In the meanwhile, I'll look for a fix for OmniFaces 1.7.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've just created the construct you suggested. Time will tell if the issues has been worked around. I'll post the results in time.

Comment: I made a fix: https://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/issues/detail?id=273 Can you please try 1.7 snapshot? https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/1.7-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Hi BalusC, sorry for not testing your fix promptly. We're dealing with a classic race against time to get our product in production for our customer. I haven't had the time to checkout the SNAPSHOT version, but will be able to test it somewhere in December or so. I'll keep you posted by means of making a comment in the issue tracker instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem looks like a race condition indeed. I have tried the workaround that BalusC suggested and I haven't seen this problem ever since.

Will wait for a version of OmniFaces that contains the fix and will then remove the workaround.

Thanks!